# How to estimate the authntiaction time

Tags: java, performance, computation

I designed an authentication protocol using java. The average excution time for a single authentication on my Desktop computer is 2.87 ms. My computer has the following specification. Windows 10 with a 1.99 GHz Intel Core i7 and 8GB of RAM.

If a number of users say 10 users preform the authentication simultaneously. What is the total computational time. Can I just say (2.87*10)?

Comment: Multiply by 10? Do a loop?

Comment: It is impossible to answer with that information. We do not even know what exactly happens and how this scales. The code could as well scale quadratic instead of linear or just being constant, depending on what it does. In which case the time might even _explode_. Everything could happen, we can not guess it.

Comment: Unless it is your server (or your job to do so on behalf of others) please don't go ahead and produce load by automating requests, some servers might blacklist you.

Comment: I designed a protcocl to perfom authntiaction, I designed the protcocl using java. The computation time for single authentication on my desktop is around 2.78 ms. Is there anyway I can tell what happen if multiple users (10 users) try to do authentication simultaneously ( can I just multiply 2.78 by 10) ? @Zabuza

Comment: I can only repeat what I said, it is impossible for us to say without the details and the code. Your assumption only works if the time is constant and does not scale linear or quadratic with load for example.

Answer (score 1):

A typical [Core i7 CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors) has between 4 and 8 cores, and can execute 6..12 threads in parallel (# cores times hyperthreading).

Assuming

- you have an i7-8650U (1.9GHz, 4 cores, hyper-threaded),
- your Java server is multithreaded (which should be the case if you use any popular implementation like Tomcat, Jetty, or alike) and
- there is no other CPU-intensive workloads running

You can say your server can handle 8 authentication requests simultaneously: 4 at full speed + 4 more at ~30% speed because of hyper-threading, or 2.87ms*1.3=3.73ms for every 8 users.

10 users will thus take around ~ 3.73ms+2.87ms = 6.6ms.

What's important when measuring Java performance, however, is to measure *steady state* under load, in order to take *garbage collection* overhead into account. When measuring a single request, you may often miss the garbage collection step entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say that the time will be multiplied by the number of users.

First of all because it would mean that your authentication mechanisms works on 1 threads, which would be terrible.

Then the time registered on your computer will for sure be different on the production or staging environment. You will have to add network hops, but on the others end servers that would do only this, but you cannot compare this time to the one on your personal computer.

If you want to test this kind of things, use performance/load testing tools. I can recommend [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) and open source tool from the Apache foundation, or [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) another open source tool for this.

They are designed to be used on such use case. With them you could then call your authentication API, for example with 100 users in 10 seconds, and you would see reports in the end which will give you your answer.